# Backbone View Events Not Firing, EL exists

Tags: backbone.js

I've been through similar discussions and still had no clue why my events are not firing. It seems I lack some fundamental understanding about how backbone events work.

Here is my code:

```
(function() { 

  MP.IndicatorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: JST['backbone/templates/indicator'],
    className: 'row indicator',

    initialize: function() {
      console.log(this);
      console.log(this.el);
      _.bindAll(this, 'collapse');
    },

    events: {
      "click .control" : "collapse"
    },

    collapse: function (e) {
      console.log('shit');
      var $el = $( e.target );

      $el.toggleClass( 'expand' );

      var $panelToPoke = $el.
        parents( '.top-container' ).
        siblings( '.bottom-container' )
      , $parentPanel = $panelToPoke.parents('.indicator')
      , isVisible = $panelToPoke.is( ':visible' );

      $parentPanel.toggleClass( 'expanded' );

      isVisible ? $panelToPoke.slideUp() : $panelToPoke.slideDown();
    },

    render: function () {
      // Don't show offers that have no transactions
      if (this.model.get('transactionCount') > 0) {
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.for_template()) );
      }
      return this.$el;
    }
  });

  MP.IndicatorsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#indicators',

    render: function () {
      var view;
      var subViews = this.collection.reduce(function ( memo, indicator ) {
        view = new MP.IndicatorView({ model: indicator });
        memo += view.render().html();
        return memo
      }, '');

      this.$el.html( subViews );
      return this;
    }
  });
})();
```

How views are instantiated:

```
var indicators = new MP.Indicators( coordinator.dump() );
var indicatorsView = new MP.IndicatorsView({ collection: indicators });
indicatorsView.render();
```

Template:

Views:

```
<div class="row indicator">

  <div class='top-container'>
    <ul class="inline-list mainpanel">
      <li>
        <div class='control expand'></div></li>
      <li class="state <%= is_active ? 'active' : 'expired' %>"></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution http://jsfiddle.net/hcKv2/
The main problem was that you are used `.html()` instead of backbone view element `.$el` inside of your `indicatorsView.render()` method.

You need to return `this` inside of render methods to achieve chain pattern, but it is not necessary it is ok if you are returning `$el` in child view.

```
render: function () {
  var view;
  var subViews = this.collection.reduce(function ( memo, indicator ) {
    view = new MP.IndicatorView({ model: indicator });
    //memo += view.render().html();
    this.$el.append( view.render() );
    // or this.$el.append( view.render().$el ); 
    // if you return this inside render method
    return memo
  }, '');

  //this.$el.html( subViews );
  return this;
}
```

Have a good coding.

Comment: Is it because html() is not accessible when the view is render() ?

Comment: oh i see...if i use html(), i am not binding that $el element to the collection view $el.. thanks a lot, Eugene !!!!

Answer (score 1):

some reference to furthur explain why:

http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/